# update a value in wp_options

Tags: options

This seams to be basic -but I don't get it.
If I query an option with get_option I get the string:

```
[{\"title\":\"Brand Primary\",\"value\":\"#2185D0\",\"_id\":\"627a0637cf178d93e50be224cc07cd6e\"},{\"title\":\"Brand Secondary\",\"value\":\"transparent\",\"_id\":\"017280d9ec94a585c2de0bee8f49d8fb\"},{\"title\":\"Typo normal\",\"value\":\"#383838\",\"_id\":\"ff77119a11466c8d7a0efd612109fe6a\"},{\"title\":\"Typo on Brand Base\",\"value\":\"#383838\",\"_id\":\"8a3c1eebb8067b37fc47fc505f44b8b4\"},{\"value\":\"rgb(255, 255, 255)\",\"title\":\"Typo on Brand Active\",\"_id\":\"66fe7ced-3ef8-4dac-92c7-568d604c2931\"}]
```

How can I change with php the value '#2185D0' (Brand Primary) and '#383838' (Brand base) without using this values by themselves (the are changing)

Comment: Are you storing it like this or is it coming from something else? Are the `\\` also in your code or did they get added when copying it from DB to here?

Comment: @kero: Thank you. I use $config = 'cornerstone_color_items'; $array = get_option($config); the result of a var_dump($array); is showing this: "string(526) "s:517:"[{\"title\":\"Brand Primary\",\"value\":\"#2185D0\",\"_id\":\"627a0637cf178d93e50be224cc07cd6e\"},{\"title\":\"Brand Secondary\",\"value\":\"transparent\",\"_id\":\"017280d9ec94a585c2de0bee8f49d8fb\"}, ... and so on - and yes the quotation marks are escaped.

Comment: This looks broken. The "s:517.." is how it is stored in the DB, but if you use `get_option` it should be just `[{"title"...`. Did you replace something in there before? Are you sure that option is currently working?

Comment: You are right. I cleand up. Now var dump shows me:
string(535) "[{\"title\":\"Brand Primary\",\"value\":\"#2185D0\",\"_id\":\"627a0637cf178d93e50be224cc07cd6e\"},{\"title\":\"Typo On Brand Color\",\"value\":\"rgb(255, 255, 255)\",\"_id\":\"017280d9ec94a585c2de0bee8f49d8fb\"},{\"title\":\"Typo normal\",\"value\":\"#383838\",\"_id\":\"ff77119a11466c8d7a0efd612109fe6a\"},.... and so on. This reflects exactly the DB-entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is escaped JSON. Formatted nicely, it looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Brand Primary",
    "value": "#2185D0",
    "_id": "627a0637cf178d93e50be224cc07cd6e"
  },
  {
    "title": "Brand Secondary",
    "value": "transparent",
    "_id": "017280d9ec94a585c2de0bee8f49d8fb"
  },
  {
    "title": "Typo normal",
    "value": "#383838",
    "_id": "ff77119a11466c8d7a0efd612109fe6a"
  },
  {
    "title": "Typo on Brand Base",
    "value": "#383838",
    "_id": "8a3c1eebb8067b37fc47fc505f44b8b4"
  },
  {
    "value": "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
    "title": "Typo on Brand Active",
    "_id": "66fe7ced-3ef8-4dac-92c7-568d604c2931"
  }
]
```

So you have an array of objects that contain titles and values.

To update a value inside it you need to:

1. Get the value.
2. Unescape it (remove the slashes).
3. Parse the JSON into a PHP array.
4. Loop over the PHP array to find the item with the title that you want to change.
5. Change the value of that item.
6. Re-encode the whole array as JSON.
7. Save the value.

So something like this:

```
$color_items = get_option( 'cornerstone_color_items' );
$color_items = stripslashes( $color_items );
$color_items = json_decode( $color_items );

foreach ( $color_items as $color_item ) {
    if ( 'Brand Primary' === $color_item->title ) {
        $color_item->value = 'NEW VALUE HERE';
        break;
    }
}

$color_items = wp_json_encode( $color_items );
$color_items = addslashes( $color_items );

update_option( 'cornerstone_color_items', $color_items );
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Jacob. I get an error "Warning: addslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in....". I believe this is, because we have still an Array and I need to encode first. Therefore we should first encode and than addslashes, shouldn't we?

Comment: Yes, sorry, those two lines are in the wrong order. I’ll fix the answer.

Comment: Again: Thank you for your great help and also the nice explanation. This helped me a lot :)